# How to embed something specific on my website for other people to use

Tags: html, embed, share

I want to make a embed code so people can use it on their website. I have pictures that I want to have embedded so people can use them on their site without downloading it.

Can someone please tell me how to do this? That would really be helpful!

Answer (score 1):

just give them the file path to the images you wish for them to be able to display that they can copy and paste it like in a textarea or something similar

```
<textarea><img src="http://yourdomain.tld/path/to/image.ext" /></textarea>
```

Comment: The thing is that i dont want people to be able to download these images, I want it coming from my website but they can make it resizable.

Comment: Like say for an example if i wanted to embed a flash game on my website, how can i share that with others instead of giving them the actual file to be downloaded or whatever

Comment: By the nature of the web, is it really possible for you to share images or flash games without letting people download the content?